# Flickering of search bar with new Products menu

Tags: bug, top-bar, search-box

Whenever you go to different pages on StackOverflow, the new search bar shortens. (you may need to open the image in a new tab).

> [image: Going to profile]

I believe this is a result of the new Products menu. Could we please fix this bug?

This seems to occur on Safari and Chrome.

Comment: This has been fixed (thank you SO developers) - **calling all mods** (@Catija) please mark as `status-completed`.